# Xamarin ios hide\remove UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uipickerview, show-hide

I've create a custom UIPickerView with "Done" button but I have trouble to remove it from screen.
This is the result of create the UIPickerView:
[image]

I've try to use this function:

```
public void removeAll(UIPickerView picker){
  this.toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview ();
  picker.RemoveFromSuperview ();
}
```

But the result is:[image]

Comment: Resolved with:
    public void removeAll(UIPickerView picker){
 this.toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview ();
 picker.Layer.Opacity = 0f;
 picker.Layer.Bounds = new  RectangleF(0,0,0,0);
 picker.RemoveFromSuperview ();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
public void removeAll(UIPickerView picker){
  this.toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview ();
  picker.Layer.Opacity = 0f;
  picker.Layer.Bounds = new  RectangleF(0,0,0,0);
  picker.RemoveFromSuperview ();
}
```